# Restkit — How to map json objects with mutable key names

Tags: ios, iphone, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have to map this structure, but I don't know how to identify the "br.myservice.com" part, because it changes and I cannot build a regular `RKObjectMapping`, as it uses fixed strings.

```
{ "objects": {
    "br.myservice.com": {
        "url": "http://br.myservice.com",
        "name": "Brazil",
        "flag": "br",
        "countries": ["br"]
    },
    "us.myservice.com": {
        "url": "http://us.myservice.com",
        "name": "United States",
        "flag": "us",
        "countries": ["us"]
  }
}
```

Comment: what you mean with it changes? the key name?

Comment: "us.myservice.com", "br.myservice.com", yes.

Comment: one outer dictionary with key "objects" and then another dictionary whose key is not fixed. so here you need to make a loop and extract them.

Comment: I know how to do this manually, @AnoopVaidya, I wan't to use the restkit object mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html#//api/name/addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute%3a) like so:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyObject class]];
mapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
[mapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"host"];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"(host).url": @"url",
    @"(host).name": @"name",
    ... and so on ....
}];
```

Comment: This is right, but there is an issue here. If the "host" is a domain name, restkit assumes each "level" of the domain is a level of the json. If it's "something.com" and I have the property "name", "email", it will try to find something.com.name, something.com.email, but the right thing would be "(something.com).email", can you think of a solution?

Comment: There are two pull requests at the moment that might help - https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1537 and https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1541

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the keys are unknown to you at the time of writing the code:

You would need to create a dynamic mapping ([`RKDynamicMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html#//api/name/setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock%3a)) with a block which inspects the received JSON dictionary and creates (and returns) a custom object mapping on the fly.

If you know the keys, just add them all and any that are appropriate will be used at runtime.